# How to enable hardware virtualisation on a ASUS VC65-C1 motherboard

Tags: bios, virtualization, asus

How can I enable hardware virtualization on an ASUS VC65-C1 motherboard. It should be able to, but I can find no where in the BIOS settings to do so.

It's running an i7-8700T CPU, BIOS Mode UEFI

Any help appreciated

Comment: Even though your CPU supports VT-x that doesn’t mean your motherboard firmware will allow you to enable it.  If there isn’t an option then VT-x can’t be enabled on your computer

Comment: Make sure you have the latest BIOS version installed. Then check if virtualization support is not already working (https://stackoverflow.com/q/49005791/150978). And if not contact the Asus support.